# Camel json validator support for json draft 07

Tags: json, validation, apache-camel

We are using Apache Camel Java DSL and the json-validator component to validate json requests against a json schema. The current camel version is 2.22.0, according to the camel documentation this supports JSON schema v4, v6, v7 and v2019-09 using the NetworkNT JSON Schema library. However, when I try a JSON schema draft 07, I get an error when running tests "Caused by: com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: Unknown Metaschema: http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#".

When i revert back to json schema draft 04 it works fine.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The default draft is the 4th one, but you can override the schema validator (JsonSchemaLoader), by defining a bean.

```
@Bean(name = "mySchemaLoader")
  public JsonSchemaLoader mySchemaLoader() {
    return (camelContext, schemaStream) -> JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V7)
        .getSchema(schemaStream);
  }
```

with that we just create a bean wich will return a V7 schema validator, if you want to override the default configuration

...

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonSchemaFactory validatorFactory =   JsonSchemaFactory.builder(JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V7)).objectMapper(mapper).build();
```

....

So having the bean, you just have to said to camel that you are going to usea that bean via query param

```
public void configureRemote() throws Exception {

    from("direct:getPrescripciones")
        .recipientList(
            simple"${header.url}?bridgeEndpoint=true"))
        .to("json-validator:deliveryReport.schema.json?schemaLoader=#bean:mySchemaLoader")
        .end();
  }
```

that's all
here the dependencies I used

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <camel.version>3.4.0</camel.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-json-validator-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jolt</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-google-pubsub-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-google-pubsub</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: If I use `.to("json-validator:deliveryReport.schema.json?schemaLoader=#bean:mySchemaLoader")` the schema isn't loaded from class path. It tries to load ist from internet. Is there any way to load it still from class path with V7?

Answer (score -1):

The camel version supporting the v7 is 3.4.0

The documentation you're looking for is on 2.x and in that case it's correctly noted that only v4 is supported: https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/json-validator-component.html

Comment: I have still the same problem with version 3.5.0.

Comment: If you want to load deliveryReport.schema.json from classpath you need to prepend classpath, so something like "json-validator:classpath:deliveryReport.schema.json"