# How to validate JSON with schema which contains a reference to another schema?

Tags: apache-camel, jsonschema, light-4j

I want to validate a JSON file with a JSON schema file, which contains a reference to another JSON schema file.

I added a [JSON Schema Validator](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/json-validator-component.html) for my Apache Camel route. Because I use JSON schema version *draft-07* and the default version is *draft-04*, I exposed a `JsonSchemaLoader`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/63417253/5277820.

The first schema `test-schema-1` is loaded from class path, but the second `test-schema-2` is loaded from internet. The used ID `http://mycompany/test-schema2.json` is only an ID not a real resource, therefore I get an exception.

Is there any way to load the second JSON schema also from class path?

**Spring Boot application**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public JsonSchemaLoader mySchemaLoader() {
    return (camelContext, schemaStream) -> 
        JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V7).getSchema(schemaStream);
  }

  @Bean
  public EndpointRouteBuilder routeBuilder() {
    return new EndpointRouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(file("d:/tmp/camel/"))
            .to(jsonValidator("/test/test-schema1.json").advanced().schemaLoader(mySchemaLoader())).stop();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**JSON schema**

`test-schema-1`:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://mycompany/test-schema1.json",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "obj": {
            "$ref": "test-schema2.json"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "target"
    ]
}
```

`test-schema-2`:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://mycompany/test-schema2.json",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "value": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
Message History (complete message history is disabled)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [from[file://d:/tmp/camel/]                                                    ] [         5]
...
[route1            ] [to1               ] [json-validator:///test/test-schema1.json?hash=93f27f49                        ] [         0]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: java.net.UnknownHostException: mycompany
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:348) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.RefValidator.getRefSchema(RefValidator.java:76) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.RefValidator.<init>(RefValidator.java:41) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.ValidatorTypeCode.newValidator(ValidatorTypeCode.java:131) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonMetaSchema.newValidator(JsonMetaSchema.java:342) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.ValidationContext.newValidator(ValidationContext.java:53) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema.read(JsonSchema.java:198) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema.initialize(JsonSchema.java:76) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.PropertiesValidator.<init>(PropertiesValidator.java:36) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.ValidatorTypeCode.newValidator(ValidatorTypeCode.java:131) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonMetaSchema.newValidator(JsonMetaSchema.java:342) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.ValidationContext.newValidator(ValidationContext.java:53) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema.read(JsonSchema.java:198) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema.initialize(JsonSchema.java:76) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.newJsonSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:254) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:296) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:304) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at test.TestApplication.lambda$0(TestApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jsonvalidator.JsonValidatorEndpoint.getOrCreateSchema(JsonValidatorEndpoint.java:162) ~[camel-json-validator-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jsonvalidator.JsonValidatorEndpoint.onExchange(JsonValidatorEndpoint.java:94) ~[camel-json-validator-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:61) ~[camel-support-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:169) ~[camel-base-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:404) ~[camel-base-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148) ~[camel-base-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60) ~[camel-base-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147) ~[camel-base-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:287) ~[camel-base-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:483) ~[camel-file-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:237) ~[camel-file-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:198) ~[camel-file-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:190) ~[camel-support-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:107) ~[camel-support-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mycompany
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:557) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520) ~[na:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.uri.URLFetcher.openConnectionCheckRedirects(URLFetcher.java:57) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.uri.URLFetcher.fetch(URLFetcher.java:43) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.uri.URISchemeFetcher.fetch(URISchemeFetcher.java:50) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:325) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.43.jar:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This is more a question about the implementation than JSON Schema.  You're correct in that the `$id` is just an identifier and not a resource.  Many implementations have a way to manually pre-load schemas so that they can be used in `$ref`s.  Maybe poke around in the [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/json-validator-component.html) for that?

Comment: Thanks, I added the tag light-4j, because it seems to be an implementation from this framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a configuration property for URI mappings, see [Configuration](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/blob/master/doc/config.md):

> - uriMappings
>
> Map of public, typically internet-accessible schema URLs to alternate locations; this  allows for offline validation of schemas that refer to public URLs. This is merged with any mappings the sonSchemaFactory may have been built.
>
> The type for this variable is Map<String, String>.

Modified code:

```java
@Bean
public JsonSchemaLoader mySchemaLoader() {

  final SchemaValidatorsConfig config = new SchemaValidatorsConfig();
  config.setUriMappings(
      Map.of("http://mycompany/test-schema2.json", "resource:/test/test-schema2.json"));

  return (camelContext, schemaStream) ->
      JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V7).getSchema(schemaStream, config);
}
```

Comment: For me this just gives UnknownHostException. I've tried all sorts of combinations of remote and local urls and nothing works :(

Comment: @Kango_V This still works in production. I also updated Apache Camel last year and it still works. What version do you use?