# Camel json schema validator with json draft 07

Tags: apache-camel, json-schema-validator

I want to use camel json schema validator in order to validate a JSON file with a JSON schema using draft 07 .

Apache Camel uses draft 04 by default and in order to change it to draft 07 I have to use a schemaLoader of type JsonSchemaLoader according to [its documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/json-validator-component.html).

How to use the schemaLoader correctly ?? I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63417253/9553481) and Apache Camel logs :

> JsonSchemaException: Validation: null is an invalid segment for URI

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we are using on our **Camel-3** project (and which is working fine):

```
public class MyFactory {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named("my-schema")
    public final JsonSchemaLoader createJsonSchemaLoader() {        
        return (camelContext, schemaStream) -> {
            SchemaValidatorsConfig conf = new SchemaValidatorsConfig();
            conf.setJavaSemantics(true);        
            conf.setFailFast(false);                    
            conf.setUriMappings(                
                Map.of(
                    "http://.../my-schema.json", "resource:META-INF/schemas/my-schema.json",                    
                )
            );          
            return JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V7).getSchema(schemaStream, conf);         
        };
    }

}


from("direct:testJson")
  .to("json-validator:META-INF/schemas/my-schema.json?schemaLoader=#my-schema")
```

Comment: Thank you, but apparently the problem was because the  "$id"s in my schema weren't URIs, so I deleted all of them and it worked fine ^^